# Need help tackling a Regular Expressions problems on Scheme Programming Language

Tags: scheme, racket

The title is most likely ambiguous to what I really mean, but I have this problem to do:

Consider the grammar for arithmetic expressions containing variables x, y, z, 
and binary operators +, * given below.

```
<expr>   ->  <term>   { + <term> } 
<term>   -> <factor>  { * <factor> } 
<factor> ->  <var>  |  ( <expr> ) 
<var>  ->  x | y| z
```

Write a function called executer in Scheme that takes an expression string 
derivable from the above grammar and outputs the value of the expression, 
assuming that x, y, and z are 2, 4, and 8 respectively. For example the call

```
(executer  "((x * x) + y * (z) + y)")
```

should produce 40. Your implementation must determine illegal expressions and be compliance
with the precedence of “*" over "+".

Now I've been trying to do this but I have no idea how I would tackle this on scheme. I was trying to figure this out myself but I opted to ask you guys for help.

Any links to documents that you think might help or to other similar code would be great.

Thanks in advance for any help I get for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: There are 2 parts to this problem:

1. Create a parser that takes a list, parses tokens, building the syntax tree as a list.
2. Create the evaluator, which takes your parsed AST and resolves (an expression) to an result.

Start with `define-type` to define your grammar.

You should try and figure out how to turn `2+3` into `(add (2 3))`, and turn that, into `5`.

Edit:

Found an old homework...here's the first few lines.  Pick out what is irrelevant ;)

```
(define-type AE
  [num (n number?)]
  [mylist (lhs AE?) (rhs list?)]
  [myhead (n list?)]
  [mytail (n list?)]
  [add (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?)]
  [mult (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?)]
  [myconcat (lhs list?) (rhs list?)])
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I'm not really very good with scheme so let's see how this goes.

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon - That's what learning is for, my friend! You're gonna feel so good when you get it working.  I think this is a very rewarding project, one that I did myself during school as well!

Comment: Thanks man. It's kinda weird working with such a different language and my brain's just not getting it well. Let's see if I can master this. Thanks!

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon - trust me, this is hard for most people to grasp.  It's a completely different way of thinking.  This is the kind of class where you curse it the whole time, and at the end you go "wow, that was really useful".  Keep updating your question with your code, and I'll keep helping you.  Also wouldn't hate the check mark ;)

Comment: It's yours. :) Let's see how this goes, I have some code that uses yacc and lex which I've been trying to hack a bit to use. As long  as I do the second part by myself I'll feel good about turning this in.

Comment: What does this do? `(define vars (make-hash))`